# Compare 2 numbers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to display the following but I'm having trouble writing the formula and would be grateful if anyone our there could help.

If B2 & C2 are not blank, display C2, otherwise display B2.
=IF(ISBLANK(B2)="","",(C2))

otherwise display B2

=IF(ISBLANK(c2)="","",(b2)), if(ISBLANK(B2)="","",(C2))

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvMab.png)

Comment: If all blank what result should be returned?

Comment: zero.  I need something that takes into account zero. Ideal output would be: 1)  B2 is blank or is zero, in which case output C2. 2)  C2 is blank or is zero, in which case output B2. 3)  Both B2 and C2 are not blank or zero, output C2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this (untested) code is what you're looking for :

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2) OR ISBLANK(C2), B2, C2)
```

Comment: thanks Harry for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are some points that need to be clarified in order to achieve whatever result you are intending to get to.  First off, here is a formula that *should* work as you've described, granted some assumptions on my part:

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2)),"",IFS(ISBLANK(B2),C2,ISBLANK(C2),B2,AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),"Double Entry"))`

To break it down...

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2)),"",...`
This section checks whether both `B2` and `C2` are *both* blank, in which case it would output nothing; however, if either `B2` or `C2` are not blank, it continues on to...

`...IFS(ISBLANK(B2),C2,ISBLANK(C2),B2,AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),"Double Entry"))`
Here we have three possible conditions that can match the case where `B2` and `C2` are not both blank, which is:

1. `B2` is blank, in which case output `C2`
2. `C2` is blank, in which case output `B2`
3. *Both* `B2` and `C2` are *not* blank, in which case output `Double Entry`.

Additional considerations:

1. The above only checks if cells are void of any input, *not* whether they display nothing.  The difference would mean that if any of them contained a formula, they would read as not being blank, i.e., `ISBLANK()` would output `FALSE`.
2. To evaluate based upon a cell's **output** instead, use `=""` for your reference comparison instead to determine whether a cell is "blank" or not.  Likewise, `=IF(LEN(A1)>0,TRUE,...)` would check whether there are any characters being output in cell A, etc.

EDIT: OP's updated criterion...

> Need to rethink because maybe ISBLANK is not the best option here
> because I need something that takes into account zero. B2 is blank or
> is zero, in which case output C2. C2 is blank or is zero, in which
> case output B2. Both B2 and C2 are not blank or zero, output C2.

The updated formula...

`=IF(OR(AND(ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2)),(AND(B2="0",C2="0"))),"",IFS(OR(ISBLANK(B2),B2="0"),C2,OR(ISBLANK(C2),C2="0"),B2,OR(AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),(AND(B2<>"0",C2<>"0"))),C2))`

Or if you anticipate non-empty cells that display blank, you can use...

`=IF(OR(AND(B2="",C2=""),(AND(B2="0",C2="0"))),"",IFS(OR(B2="",B2="0"),C2,OR(C2="",C2="0"),B2,OR(AND(B2<>"",C2<>""),(AND(B2<>"0",C2<>"0"))),C2))`

That should fulfill your requirements?  Though I should clarify, when you say...

> Both B2 and C2 are not blank or zero, output C2.

You mean both `B2` and `C2` are **not blank**, and both `B2` and `C2` are **not zero**, correct?

Comment: thanks Arctiic for your suggestion and the detailed breakdown.

Comment: Need to rethink because maybe ISBLANK is not the best option here because I need something that takes into account zero.  

    B2 is blank or is zero, in which case output C2.

    C2 is blank or is zero, in which case output B2.

    Both B2 and C2 are not blank or zero, output C2.

Comment: @tmc_m Edited answer to fulfill the clarified criterion.  Please review and let me know if I've understood your parameters correctly.

Comment: Many thanks Arctiic.  Looks good.  Will review this weekend and return.